# SSRS Subscription ParameterValueOrFieldReference Default Value

Tags: c#, reporting-services, native, reporting, ssrs-2019

We have a .rdl file with parameters Available values coming from Query.

In the cascade drop down one of the parameter, we have set available values from query and also set default value -1
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ9ZR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZAfW.png)

We are using reportinservice2010.asmx for creating subscription by passing parameters like below

```cs
List<ParameterValueOrFieldReference> parameters =
    new List<ParameterValueOrFieldReference>();
parameters.AddRange(
    rpt.ParameterNameMappings
    .Where(p => p.IsMappingFieldAlias)
    .Select(p => new ParameterFieldReference()
    { 
       ParameterName = p.ParameterName,
       FieldAlias = p.ParameterFieldAliasOrValue }));
parameters.AddRange(
    rpt.ParameterNameMappings
    .Where(p => !p.IsMappingFieldAlias)
    .Select(p => new ParameterValue()
    { 
       Name = p.ParameterName,
       Value = p.ParameterFieldAliasOrValue }));
```

Above parameters we are using below:

```cs
rs.CreateDataDrivenSubscription(
    report.FullName
    , settings
    , report.ReportSubscription.SubscriptionDataRetrievalPlan
    , report.ReportSubscription.Description
    , report.ReportSubscription.EventType
    , report.ReportSubscription.MatchData
    , reportParameters)
```

Problem : The subscription is getting created but the default values are not set in the screen of subscription edit. Other parameters which are not default are getting saved as Get Value from Dataset.

Solution : We need by default to set as "Use Default value"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeorT.png)

Give solution to get use default values

Comment: Where does the `settings` parameter variable/field/property get created?

Comment: ExtensionSettings settings = report.ReportSubscription.ReportSubscriptionExtension.ToReportingServicesExtensionSettings(report.ReportSubscription.IsDataDriven);